# How to pass values with POST on Django?

Tags: python, django, post

I try to do a simple database interaction/crud thing with Django.
For now, I just did a simple view to display the information from the database on an html table, and I'm trying to add a functionality that would add new informations to the database.

For this, I have an input field for every table column present in the table, and an add button to add in the database. I wanted to make it work with a POST method. The POST request would be computed on the view that would add the new values on the database, and redirect on the page with the html table that will then display the added information.

However, I didn't quite managed to find a solution to what I need to do.

This is the views.py I have at the moment:

```
from orders.models import Order #my model

class OrdersList(TemplateView):
    template_name = "orderlist.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(OrdersList, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        orders = Order.objects.all()
        #adding values from the model to the context
        context['orders'] = []
        i = 0
        for order in orders:
            context['orders'].append(i)
            context['orders'][i] = {}
            context['orders'][i]['id'] = i+1
            context['orders'][i]['market_place'] = order.market_place
            context['orders'][i]['purchase_date'] = order.purchase_date
            context['orders'][i]['purchase_time'] = order.purchase_time
            context['orders'][i]['amount'] = order.amount
            context['orders'][i]['currency'] = order.currency
            i = i + 1
        #eventually, context['orders'] will be an array of dictionaries, one for each order present in the model
        return context
```

and my urls.py

```
from orders.views import *

urlpatterns = [
    path('', OrdersList.as_view(), name='home'),
    path('add/', AddOrder.as_view(), name='add')
]
```

So I was about to make the AddOrder class on the views that would take the values sent through the POST method, add them on the database, and return the orderlist.html

However, when I tried to find answers on the net, it was all on urls.py file working with url() lines, and the views.py with one function for each view; whereas I learned Django with the path() on urls.py and one class for each view on views.py, so this is how I tried things, but I don't know how to do.

EDIT: I wasn't clear enough on that aspect, but the template has a form on the table that will send a POST request to the /add/ url.

Comment: I really can't understand what you're trying to do here. What does any of this code have to do with POSTing the data? Why do you want an array of dicts? Why don't you just pass the orders to the template directly? (And there is absolutely *no difference* at this level between url and path).

Comment: Prior to Django 2, the url patterns were defined with `url` instead of `path` (and worked a bit differently). So you'll find a lot of references on the internet that use `url`. It doesn't make a big difference. But what you want to do is create a form and a view that processes the form. That's basic Django, you should do the entire [Django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/intro/)  it will teach you how to work with forms and process submitted data.

Comment: And if you want to create a form for each row in a queryset, you probably want a formset. But this doesn't explain why you want lists of dicts rather than just sending the queryset directly, nor does it tell us anything about how you're actually processing the POSTed data and where the actual problem is.

Comment: Maybe you need `ajax`?